# How to use output text date format to respect locale

Tags: visualforce, bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Visualforce Locale specific date format](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/476/visualforce-locale-specific-date-format)

Is there anyway to get the `<apex:outputtext>` tag to respect a user's locale when printing out dates?

Example Controller:

```
public class Example {
  public Date dateVariables { get { return Date.today(); } }
}
```

Example Page:

```
<apex:page controller="Example">
  <apex:outputText value="{0, date, short}">
    <apex:param value="{!dateVariable}"/>
  </apex:outputText>
</apex:page>
```

Output is always MM/DD/YY, when I'd expect it to be DD/MM/YY for European user locale's.  The [java message format documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) gives the impression that this considers locale, but I'm guessing SFDC is not passing it to the message format class.  Hopefully there is a better way to attack this.

Additional Details:

I have to use outputtext over outputfield for performance reasons since the page is an export of 1000s of records.

Comment: This is  exact same scenario as : http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/476/visualforce-locale-specific-date-format. In case you are using a outputtext can you not use .format() on {!datevariable}

Comment: @rao thanks for the link, shame on me for not seeing that one already ;)

Comment: @rao, d'oh the other question implies this should work even though it doesn't

Comment: Ralph I think the way the post suggests is lil different. You are using a string to get the param value, but the post uses sobject.field_name. Are u pulling in a field from the standardcontroller to display as output text, if so can u try something like opportunity.name and see if it works ?

Comment: @rao, I'm not sure I follow about using the string to get the param value, added a controller to clarify.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.interactiveties.com/b_locale_datetime.php

Just go through this blog there is a component built by the author and its really aweosme

```
public class controller_locale_formatted_datetime {

public DateTime date_time { get; set; } //property that reads the datetime value from the component attribute tag

//returns the properly formatted datetime value
public String getTimeZoneValue() {
    Map<String, String> mappedValues = new Map<String, String>(); //map for holding locale to datetime format
    mappedValues = MapValues(); //populate the map with all the locale specific datetime formats
    String user_locale = UserInfo.getLocale(); //grab the locale of the user
    String datetime_format = 'M/d/yyyy h:mm a'; //variable for the datetime format defaulted to the US format
    if (mappedValues.containsKey(user_locale)) { //if the map contains the correct datetime format
        datetime_format = mappedValues.get(user_locale); //grab the datetime format for the locale
    }
    String locale_formatted_date_time_value = date_time.format(datetime_format); //create a string with the proper format
    return locale_formatted_date_time_value; //return the string
}

//populate a map with locale values and corresponding datetime formats
private Map<String, String> MapValues() {
    Map<String, String> locale_map = new Map<String, String>(); //holds the locale to timedate formats
    locale_map.put('ar', 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a');
    locale_map.put('ar_AE', 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a');
    locale_map.put('ar_BH', 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a');
    locale_map.put('ar_JO', 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a');
    locale_map.put('ar_KW', 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a');
    locale_map.put('ar_LB', 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a');
    locale_map.put('ar_SA', 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a');
    locale_map.put('bg_BG', 'yyyy-M-d H:mm');
    locale_map.put('ca', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm');
    locale_map.put('ca_ES', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm');
    locale_map.put('ca_ES_EURO', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm');
    locale_map.put('cs', 'd.M.yyyy H:mm');
    locale_map.put('cs_CZ', 'd.M.yyyy H:mm');
    locale_map.put('da', 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm');
    locale_map.put('da_DK', 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm');
    locale_map.put('de', 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm');
    locale_map.put('de_AT', 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm');
    locale_map.put('de_AT_EURO', 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm');
    locale_map.put('de_CH', 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm');
    locale_map.put('de_DE', 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm');
    locale_map.put('de_DE_EURO', 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm');
    locale_map.put('de_LU', 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm');
    locale_map.put('de_LU_EURO', 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm');
    locale_map.put('el_GR', 'd/M/yyyy h:mm a');
    locale_map.put('en_AU', 'd/MM/yyyy HH:mm');
    locale_map.put('en_B', 'M/d/yyyy h:mm a');
    locale_map.put('en_BM', 'M/d/yyyy h:mm a');
    locale_map.put('en_CA', 'dd/MM/yyyy h:mm a');
    locale_map.put('en_GB', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm');
    locale_map.put('en_GH', 'M/d/yyyy h:mm a');
    locale_map.put('en_ID', 'M/d/yyyy h:mm a');
    locale_map.put('en_IE', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm');
    locale_map.put('en_IE_EURO', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm');
    locale_map.put('en_NZ', 'd/MM/yyyy HH:mm');
    locale_map.put('en_SG', 'M/d/yyyy h:mm a');
    locale_map.put('en_US', 'M/d/yyyy h:mm a');
    locale_map.put('en_ZA', 'yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm a');
    locale_map.put('es', 'd/MM/yyyy H:mm');
    locale_map.put('es_AR', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm');
    locale_map.put('es_BO', 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a');
    locale_map.put('es_CL', 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a');
    locale_map.put('es_CO', 'd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a');
    locale_map.put('es_CR', 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a');
    locale_map.put('es_EC', 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a');
    locale_map.put('es_ES', 'd/MM/yyyy H:mm');
    locale_map.put('es_ES_EURO', 'd/MM/yyyy H:mm');
    locale_map.put('es_GT', 'd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a');
    locale_map.put('es_HN', 'MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm a');
    locale_map.put('es_MX', 'd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a');
    locale_map.put('es_PE', 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a');
    locale_map.put('es_PR', 'MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm a');
    locale_map.put('es_PY', 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a');
    locale_map.put('es_SV', 'MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm a');
    locale_map.put('es_UY', 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a');
    locale_map.put('es_VE', 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a');
    locale_map.put('et_EE', 'd.MM.yyyy H:mm');
    locale_map.put('fi', 'd.M.yyyy H:mm');
    locale_map.put('fi_FI', 'd.M.yyyy H:mm');
    locale_map.put('fi_FI_EURO', 'd.M.yyyy H:mm');
    locale_map.put('fr', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm');
    locale_map.put('fr_BE', 'd/MM/yyyy H:mm');
    locale_map.put('fr_CA', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm');
    locale_map.put('fr_CH', 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm');
    locale_map.put('fr_FR', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm');
    locale_map.put('fr_FR_EURO', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm');
    locale_map.put('fr_LU', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm');
    locale_map.put('fr_MC', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm');
    locale_map.put('hr_HR', 'yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm');
    locale_map.put('hu', 'yyyy.MM.dd. H:mm');
    locale_map.put('hy_AM', 'M/d/yyyy h:mm a');
    locale_map.put('is_IS', 'd.M.yyyy HH:mm');
    locale_map.put('it', 'dd/MM/yyyy H.mm');
    locale_map.put('it_CH', 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm');
    locale_map.put('it_IT', 'dd/MM/yyyy H.mm');
    locale_map.put('iw', 'HH:mm dd/MM/yyyy');
    locale_map.put('iw_IL', 'HH:mm dd/MM/yyyy');
    locale_map.put('ja', 'yyyy/MM/dd H:mm');
    locale_map.put('ja_JP', 'yyyy/MM/dd H:mm');
    locale_map.put('kk_KZ', 'M/d/yyyy h:mm a');
    locale_map.put('km_KH', 'M/d/yyyy h:mm a');
    locale_map.put('ko', 'yyyy. M. d a h:mm');
    locale_map.put('ko_KR', 'yyyy. M. d a h:mm');
    locale_map.put('lt_LT', 'yyyy.M.d HH.mm');
    locale_map.put('lv_LV', 'yyyy.d.M HH:mm');
    locale_map.put('ms_MY', 'dd/MM/yyyy h:mm a');
    locale_map.put('nl', 'd-M-yyyy H:mm');
    locale_map.put('nl_BE', 'd/MM/yyyy H:mm');
    locale_map.put('nl_NL', 'd-M-yyyy H:mm');
    locale_map.put('nl_SR', 'd-M-yyyy H:mm');
    locale_map.put('no', 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm');
    locale_map.put('no_NO', 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm');
    locale_map.put('pl', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm');
    locale_map.put('pt', 'dd-MM-yyyy H:mm');
    locale_map.put('pt_AO', 'dd-MM-yyyy H:mm');
    locale_map.put('pt_BR', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm');
    locale_map.put('pt_PT', 'dd-MM-yyyy H:mm');
    locale_map.put('ro_RO', 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm');
    locale_map.put('ru', 'dd.MM.yyyy H:mm');
    locale_map.put('sk_SK', 'd.M.yyyy H:mm');
    locale_map.put('sl_SI', 'd.M.y H:mm');
    locale_map.put('sv', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm');
    locale_map.put('sv_SE', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm');
    locale_map.put('th', 'M/d/yyyy h:mm a');
    locale_map.put('th_TH', 'd/M/yyyy, H:mm ?.');
    locale_map.put('tr', 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm');
    locale_map.put('ur_PK', 'M/d/yyyy h:mm a');
    locale_map.put('vi_VN', 'HH:mm dd/MM/yyyy');
    locale_map.put('zh', 'yyyy-M-d ah:mm');
    locale_map.put('zh_CN', 'yyyy-M-d ah:mm');
    locale_map.put('zh_HK', 'yyyy-M-d ah:mm');
    locale_map.put('zh_TW', 'yyyy/M/d a h:mm');
    return locale_map; //return the map
}

 }
```

Componet code

```
<apex:component access="global" controller="controller_locale_formatted_datetime"> 
<apex:attribute assignTo="{!date_time}" description="The DateTime value to be rendered    based upon the user's locale" name="date_time_value" type="DateTime"></apex:attribute>
 {!TimeZoneValue}
</apex:component>
```

An example on how to use this code

```
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" title="Formatted System Information">
            <apex:outputField value="{!Account.CreatedById}">,      <c:locale_formatted_datetime date_time_value="{!Account.CreatedDate}"></c:locale_formatted_datetime></apex:outputField>
            <apex:outputField value="{!Account.LastModifiedById}">,   <c:locale_formatted_datetime date_time_value="{!Account.LastModifiedDate}"> </c:locale_formatted_datetime></apex:outputField>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately since I'm outputting a lot of records using this component would blow out the view state.  Probably not a big deal, but would prefer not to have to update the component as new locales are added if there is anyway to make it happen dynamically

Answer (score 0):

Ralph

I tried the following and it works as per user's Locale :
the .format() should convert a date variable into a string which would be a date based on users locale
[image]

I used the .format() on the date field and it worked as said @Rob Scott in the post : 
[Visualforce Locale specific date format](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/476/visualforce-locale-specific-date-format)

Page :

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="account" extensions="outtext_controller">
<apex:outputText value="{!datevalue}"/>
</apex:page>
```

controller:

```
public with sharing class outtext_controller {
public string datevalue{get;set;}
    public outtext_controller(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    Account acc = [select id,createddate,date_val__c from account where id=:apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id')];
    datevalue = acc.date_val__c.format();
    }
}
```

Comment: you're correct .format() respects locale, but the question is if there is anyway to get apex:outputText using the java message patter to work with locale

Comment: @Ralph Look at this post by techgerm http://www.tgerm.com/2011/01/message-format-string-format-apex.html 
This might give you some more insight if u did not stumble on this link. The link says that the format can take only string arguments and cannot take datatime, date, currency and number etc,

Comment: thanks for the link, i'm not using the apex format function, just the implied format functioned used in the apex:outputtext which can take datetime, date, currency, number formats.  I've run into the .format() limitation, very annoying given it doesn't correspond with the functionality apex:outputText format strings.  Of course, there are instance methods for Date (but no format string input) and DateTime (can pass it a format string)