# Visualforce Date formatting in arbitrary Locale

Tags: visualforce, date, formatting

So I know I can format dates like

```
<apex:outputText value="{0, date, MMMM d','  yyyy}">
    <apex:param value="{!contact.Birthdate}" /> 
</apex:outputText>
```

and this outputs e.g. `January 5, 2016`.

But what if I want this to show in e.g. *Dutch*, so that the date would become `5 januari, 2016`. Can this be done by changing the above outputText or should I roll my own property on the controller that generates the date for me? In case of the latter, is there a standard library that already does this?

Comment: So for a User whose locale is set to one value, you want to format specific date fields in another locale? Interested to know why...

Comment: It's for visualforce email templates where we send mail to contacts in their own locale.

Comment: Looks like a common problem with no clean solution e.g. [Visualforce Email template to display date and time in User's timezone (local time)](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000098DmIAI).

Comment: Presumably the templates are not Visualforce where the [apex:page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_page.htm) language attribute could be used (which I assume affects date format as well as labels)?

Comment: @WillemMulder could you find a solution for displaying locale based day names ?

Answer (score 1):

```
{! DAY(Contact.BirthDate)}
<apex:outputText value="{!CASE(MONTH(Contact.BirthDate),
                        1, 'Januari',
                        2, 'Februari',
                        3, 'Maart', 
                        4, 'April', 
                        5, 'Mei', 
                        6, 'Juni',
                        7, 'Juli',
                        8, 'Augustus',
                        9, 'September',
                        10, 'Oktober',
                        11, 'November',
                        12, 'December',
                        '-')}" />
{!YEAR(Contact.BirthDate)}
```

Answer (score 1):

A few years late, but I think ultimately you are not going to find a satisfactory answer to this. Salesforce has not given Visualforce/Apex access to a comprehensive resource for international day/month names.

Your best bet might be to make a reusable Visualforce component. The component can take in a Date or Datetime and have a controller of its own that retrieves day/month maps from some source (Custom Metadata? Labels? Etc) and does the formatting. You'll end up with reusable code you can use in many projects, and then you can include it in VF with a simple tag syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing this - may be work

```
<apex:outputText value="{0,date,dd MMMM',' yyyy}">
    <apex:param value="{!contact.Birthdate}" /> 
</apex:outputText>
```

**Edit :**

If not expected result then Go through this - (Talking about Locality)

[How to use output text date format to respect locale](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/6065/how-to-use-output-text-date-format-to-respect-locale)

[Visualforce Component for Locale Based DateTime Display](http://www.interactiveties.com/b_locale_datetime.php#.VhPB2PmqpHw)

Comment: Yes I tried that already, it only moves things around, it doesn't actually translate into a different locale.

Comment: check out edits

Comment: Thanks, that is useful for half of the question: how to order the different date elements. The other part still stands: how to actually translate and display the MMMM part.