# Formatting EndDate in VisualForce email template

Tags: visualforce, email-template

So:

```
{!relatedTo.K__EndDate__c}
```

Gives me: "Wed Apr 02 00:00:00 GMT 2014"

What would I use if I want:

"Wed Apr 02 2014"

i.e. suppressing the time part.

Thx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a parameterised `outputText` with a Java-style format string in your Visualforce page to do this:

```
<apex:outputText value="{0,date,EEE MMM dd yyyy}">
    <apex:param value="{!relatedTo.K__EndDate__c}" /> 
</apex:outputText>
```

This is covered in more detail in the documentation [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_outputText.htm).

> Use with nested param tags to format the text values, where {n} corresponds to the n-th nested param tag. The `value` attribute supports the same syntax as the MessageFormat class in Java. See [the MessageFormat class JavaDocs](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) for more information.

Comment: Is there a locale-respecting way to do this?

Comment: @KeithC You can use `.format()` in a controller to produce a formatted string in the user's locale. As soon as you start getting into specific formats such as the above it's very hard to respect locale. Salesforce provides `short`, `medium` and `long` date formats, but these are always US localised, despite the documentation suggesting otherwise. This is talked about in this answer (http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/488/5460), which seems to infer that this will never be fixed.

Comment: You can also use `apex:outputField` which respects locale (unlike `apex:outputText`, but you have no control over the format when you do this, it just uses the default for the user's locale.