# What other parameters does Date.parse(str) accepts other than str = 09/09/2018?

Tags: apex, date

I was testing Date.parse(str) method with following types of inputs:

- `String str1 = '06/06/2016'`
- `String str2 = '06-06-2016'`
- `String str3 = '2016-06-06'`
- `String str4 = 'July 6th, 2016'`
- `String str5 = '06, 06, 2016'`
- `String str6 = '06 July, 2016'`

Out of all above inputs, `str1` is the only valid input and the `Date.parse` method does not work for the other formats. Does the `Date.parse` method support only the format followed by `str1`? Or does parse have a bigger picture than this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The input will only accept one format, and that format is based on the running user's locale. Note from the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_date.htm) (emphasis mine):

> **parse(stringDate)**
>   Constructs a Date from a String. *The format of the String depends on the local date format.*

You can see how to get the format accepted by the running user as provided by @cropredy on this question: [Get dateformat based on Locale](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/133534/get-dateformat-based-on-locale).

So yes, for any given user, there is only one locale format that will work. For example, if you changed your locale to `'de'`, then you would have to specify `Date.parse('25.12.2016')` and an input of `'06/06/2016'` would error. If your locale is `'es'` than it would be `'25/12/2016'`, and if your locale is `en_US` then you would use `'12/25/2016'`.