# Dateformat based on user locale

Tags: locale

I am using [aljs](http://aljs.appiphony.com/#!/) library to show [datepicker](http://aljs.appiphony.com/#!/datepickers).I need to format the selected date as per the date format of current user locale using moment.js

`moment(selectedDate).format(dateFormat)`

But I need all the date formats for all locales. I am unable to find any documentation on this. Although [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/133534/get-dateformat-based-on-locale) is solution provided but it does not handle all the locales.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code

```
    private static Map<String, String> localeToDateTimeFmtMap;             // Singleton, remember when first referenced
//  -------------------------------------------------------
//  getUserDateFormat: e.g. M/d/yyyy
//  -------------------------------------------------------
    public static String getUserDateFormat()
    {
        String userLocale = UserInfo.getLocale();
        getLocaleToDateTimeFmtMap();
        if (!localeToDateTimeFmtMap.containsKey(userLocale)) return 'yyyy-mm-dd';
        return localeToDateTimeFmtMap.get(userLocale).substringBefore(' ');
    }

//  -------------------------------------------------------
//  getUserDateTimeFormat: e.g. M/d/yyyy hh.mm.ss
//  -------------------------------------------------------
    public static String getUserDateTimeFormat()
    {
        String userLocale = UserInfo.getLocale();
        getLocaleToDateTimeFmtMap();
        if (!localeToDateTimeFmtMap.containsKey(userLocale)) return 'yyyy-mm-dd hh.mm.ss';
        return localeToDateTimeFmtMap.get(userLocale);
    }

//  -------------------------------------------------------
//  getLocaleToDateTimeFmtMap                   : Returns a map of user locale | datetime format for that locale (http://www.interactiveties.com/b_locale_datetime.php)
//  -------------------------------------------------------
    public static Map<String, String> getLocaleToDateTimeFmtMap()
    {
        if (localeToDateTimeFmtMap == null)
            localeToDateTimeFmtMap = new Map<String, String>
            {
                    'ar' => 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a',
                    'ar_AE' => 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a',
                    'ar_BH' => 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a',
                    'ar_JO' => 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a',
                    'ar_KW' => 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a',
                    'ar_LB' => 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a',
                    'ar_SA' => 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a',
                    'bg_BG' => 'yyyy-M-d H:mm',
                    'ca' => 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm',
                    'ca_ES' => 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm',
                    'ca_ES_EURO' => 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm',
                    'cs' => 'd.M.yyyy H:mm',
                    'cs_CZ' => 'd.M.yyyy H:mm',
                    'da' => 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm',
                    'da_DK' => 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm',
                    'de' => 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm',
                    'de_AT' => 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm',
                    'de_AT_EURO' => 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm',
                    'de_CH' => 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm',
                    'de_DE' => 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm',
                    'de_DE_EURO' => 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm',
                    'de_LU' => 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm',
                    'de_LU_EURO' => 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm',
                    'el_GR' => 'd/M/yyyy h:mm a',
                    'en_AU' => 'd/MM/yyyy HH:mm',
                    'en_B' => 'M/d/yyyy h:mm a',
                    'en_BM' => 'M/d/yyyy h:mm a',
                    'en_CA' => 'dd/MM/yyyy h:mm a',
                    'en_GB' => 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm',
                    'en_GH' => 'M/d/yyyy h:mm a',
                    'en_ID' => 'M/d/yyyy h:mm a',
                    'en_IE' => 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm',
                    'en_IE_EURO' => 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm',
                    'en_NZ' => 'd/MM/yyyy HH:mm',
                    'en_SG' => 'M/d/yyyy h:mm a',
                    'en_US' => 'M/d/yyyy h:mm a',
                    'en_ZA' => 'yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm a',
                    'es' => 'd/MM/yyyy H:mm',
                    'es_AR' => 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm',
                    'es_BO' => 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a',
                    'es_CL' => 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a',
                    'es_CO' => 'd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a',
                    'es_CR' => 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a',
                    'es_EC' => 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a',
                    'es_ES' => 'd/MM/yyyy H:mm',
                    'es_ES_EURO' => 'd/MM/yyyy H:mm',
                    'es_GT' => 'd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a',
                    'es_HN' => 'MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm a',
                    'es_MX' => 'd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a',
                    'es_PE' => 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a',
                    'es_PR' => 'MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm a',
                    'es_PY' => 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a',
                    'es_SV' => 'MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm a',
                    'es_UY' => 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a',
                    'es_VE' => 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a',
                    'et_EE' => 'd.MM.yyyy H:mm',
                    'fi' => 'd.M.yyyy H:mm',
                    'fi_FI' => 'd.M.yyyy H:mm',
                    'fi_FI_EURO' => 'd.M.yyyy H:mm',
                    'fr' => 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm',
                    'fr_BE' => 'd/MM/yyyy H:mm',
                    'fr_CA' => 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm',
                    'fr_CH' => 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm',
                    'fr_FR' => 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm',
                    'fr_FR_EURO' => 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm',
                    'fr_LU' => 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm',
                    'fr_MC' => 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm',
                    'hr_HR' => 'yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm',
                    'hu' => 'yyyy.MM.dd. H:mm',
                    'hy_AM' => 'M/d/yyyy h:mm a',
                    'is_IS' => 'd.M.yyyy HH:mm',
                    'it' => 'dd/MM/yyyy H.mm',
                    'it_CH' => 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm',
                    'it_IT' => 'dd/MM/yyyy H.mm',
                    'iw' => 'HH:mm dd/MM/yyyy',
                    'iw_IL' => 'HH:mm dd/MM/yyyy',
                    'ja' => 'yyyy/MM/dd H:mm',
                    'ja_JP' => 'yyyy/MM/dd H:mm',
                    'kk_KZ' => 'M/d/yyyy h:mm a',
                    'km_KH' => 'M/d/yyyy h:mm a',
                    'ko' => 'yyyy. M. d a h:mm',
                    'ko_KR' => 'yyyy. M. d a h:mm',
                    'lt_LT' => 'yyyy.M.d HH.mm',
                    'lv_LV' => 'yyyy.d.M HH:mm',
                    'ms_MY' => 'dd/MM/yyyy h:mm a',
                    'nl' => 'd-M-yyyy H:mm',
                    'nl_BE' => 'd/MM/yyyy H:mm',
                    'nl_NL' => 'd-M-yyyy H:mm',
                    'nl_SR' => 'd-M-yyyy H:mm',
                    'no' => 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm',
                    'no_NO' => 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm',
                    'pl' => 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm',
                    'pt' => 'dd-MM-yyyy H:mm',
                    'pt_AO' => 'dd-MM-yyyy H:mm',
                    'pt_BR' => 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm',
                    'pt_PT' => 'dd-MM-yyyy H:mm',
                    'ro_RO' => 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm',
                    'ru' => 'dd.MM.yyyy H:mm',
                    'sk_SK' => 'd.M.yyyy H:mm',
                    'sl_SI' => 'd.M.y H:mm',
                    'sv' => 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm',
                    'sv_SE' => 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm',
                    'th' => 'M/d/yyyy h:mm a',
                    'th_TH' => 'd/M/yyyy, H:mm ?.',
                    'tr' => 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm',
                    'ur_PK' => 'M/d/yyyy h:mm a',
                    'vi_VN' => 'HH:mm dd/MM/yyyy',
                    'zh' => 'yyyy-M-d ah:mm',
                    'zh_CN' => 'yyyy-M-d ah:mm',
                    'zh_HK' => 'yyyy-M-d ah:mm',
                    'zh_TW' => 'yyyy/M/d a h:mm'
            };
        return localeToDateTimeFmtMap;
    }
```

And a complete list of all the locales can be found here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_supported_locales.htm&type=0